# Memory issues on rescaling bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

So, I have this test project where I try to circumnavigate issues that I find with bitmaps and I'm having more issues than usual with resizing bitmaps. The project, pre-resizing tests, allowed me to load a bitmap from a stream, show it, and dispose it. In a loop.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle){
    ...
    int i = 0;
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer (100);
    t.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        RunOnUiThread(delegate() {
            if(i++ % 2 == 0){
                Console.WriteLine("Iteration no: " + i);
                tmpView tView = new tmpView(this);
                mainView.AddView(tView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
            }else{
                 ((tmpView)mainView.GetChildAt(0)).dispose();
                 mainView.RemoveAllViews();
            }
        });

    };
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Start ();
}
```

and the tmpView code:

```
private class tmpView:RelativeLayout{
    PTImage img;
    ImageView img2;
    PTImageObj imgObj;
    Android.Graphics.Bitmap bmp;
    Bitmap resized;
    public tmpView(Context cntx):base(cntx){
        SetBackgroundColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(200, 0, 0, 200));
        System.IO.Stream imgStream = Application.Context.Assets.Open ("backgroundLeft.png");
        bmp = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (imgStream, new Android.Graphics.Rect(), new Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options(){InPurgeable = true, InInputShareable = true});
        img2 = new ImageView(cntx);
        img2.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
        imgStream.Close();
        imgStream.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(imgStream);
        imgStream = null;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 500);
        lp.TopMargin = 150;
        this.AddView(img2, lp);
    }

    public void dispose(){
        bmp.Recycle ();
        img2.SetImageDrawable (null);
    }
}
```

So far that works fine, I can leave it iterating for as long as I want without having outOfMemory issues. However, if I want to change the tmpView code to this:

```
public tmpView(Context cntx):base(cntx){
    SetBackgroundColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(200, 0, 0, 200));
    System.IO.Stream imgStream = Application.Context.Assets.Open ("backgroundLeft.png");
    bmp = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (imgStream, new Android.Graphics.Rect(), new Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options(){InPurgeable = true, InInputShareable = true});
    resized = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.Width + 50, bmp.Height + 50, false);
    bmp.Recycle();
    img2 = new ImageView(cntx);
    img2.SetImageBitmap(resized);
    imgStream.Close();
    imgStream.Dispose();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(imgStream);
    imgStream = null;
}
```

I end up with outOfMemory issues at about ~200 iterations. My guess is that the rescaling is creating temp bitmaps that I can't force recycle. Is there a better way of resizing the bitmap so I can continue the loop without crashing?

Note: if I don't actually resize, if I give the `CreateScaledBitmap` the same sizes the bitmap has, I don't run into the memory issues. But... that kind of defeats the purpose :P. Oh, and yes, I did add the `resized.Recycle ();` in the `dispose`

Note2: The code is in C# but I'm fine with answers in java

Thank you,

Axel

Comment: Could it be caused by just drawing over 200 imageViews? is it still crashing if you remove the addView calls?

Comment: Well, I still need to add/remove something, it's either the tmpView class I created or an imageVIew. I ill try moving the add/remove to the imageview, but why do I have issues only when I add the resize part?

Comment: You mean you were able to draw that 200 imageviews, but when you added that resize code it begins to crash? Can you post your full tmpView class?

Comment: What I meant is that I was able to let the timer in the `OnCreate` run for a long time and I never saw any outOfMemory issues. Way past 200 iterations. I'll add what's left of the tmpView code but the constructor and the dispose is pretty much it.

Comment: There, I added the full code. Btw, following your comment I also tried to change the code inside the timer where instead of addidn and disposing a tmpView I just have a persistent imageView where I add/remove a bitmap. The code is the same that the one inside the tmpView for loadng the bitmap. Again, if I jsut add/remove a bitmap I can let the timer go for as long as I want, if I try to add/remove a resized bitmap, it crashes

Comment: Try adding resized.Recycle(); just before setting it to the imageview. Anyway im mostly thinking you will need the largeHeap attribute on the manifest for this to work.

Comment: I can't do that, I would get an exception for trying to use a recycled bitmap. Also, adding a large heap wouldn't solve the issue, it would only allow the timer to run for a longer period of time before crashing. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry was meaning after setting it to the imageview not before, and right, if your loop is going to be infinite then it doesnt matter how much memory you can alloc, but i hope that isnt the goal...

Comment: Yeah, just tried to add the `recycle` after the `SetImageBitmap` and it will complain about using a recycled bitmap. Also, the intent kinda is to have an infifnite loop. My actual app works with many bitmaps and sometimes I run into memory issues. So, I want to be able to be certain that I can truly clear bitmaps from memory and I tought this little test would help me out. Currently, it does fine, untill I try to resize.